# set two textviews programatically while parsing

Tags: android, textview

I have a piece of code that is parsing my xml values to my android activity, i need to show the  parsed xml values in two textviews in horizantal orientation programatically, the values of each textview should be in vertical orientation . I got the textviews in unstructured way. I need to show the text views in structured way. Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem.
  eg for unstructured output:

```
      flag
              false
      id
                0
```

I need an output like

```
      flag   false

      id     0
```

I created textviews like this

```
    private void createTextView(String text, LinearLayout root, int textSize,
        int width, int height, int gravity) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,
            height);
    if (gravity == Gravity.RIGHT) {
        params.setMargins(300, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (gravity == Gravity.LEFT) {
        params.setMargins(150, 0, 0, 0);

    }
    if (gravity == Gravity.CENTER) {
        params.setMargins(20, 5, 0, 5);

    }
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(textSize);
    textView.setGravity(params.gravity);

    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(
            android.R.color.black));
    root.addView(textView);
}


           private void createTextViewsWithHorizontalOrient(String textOne,
        String textTwo, LinearLayout root) {
    LinearLayout horizontalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout horizontalNextLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

    horizontalLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    horizontalLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    horizontalNextLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    horizontalNextLinearLayout
            .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    horizontalNextLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    horizontalLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    createTextView(textOne, horizontalLinearLayout, 18,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.LEFT);

    createTextView(textTwo, horizontalNextLinearLayout, 18,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.RIGHT);
    root.addView(horizontalLinearLayout);
    root.addView(horizontalNextLinearLayout);

}
```

I got the solution in the method create textview change layout params

```
               private void createTextView(String text, LinearLayout root,
                          int textSize,int width, int height, int gravity) {

                        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,
                         height);
              createTextView(textTwo, horizontalNextLinearLayout, 18,
              android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              Gravity.LEFT);
```

Comment: so what is the output of this?

Comment: I have edited my output example just now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your naming convention is bad. You have *horizontalLinearLayout* which has orientation set to vertical.

Secondly, I assume that your root view is LinearLayout with vertical orientation. So it's obvious, that you get this output. What you should do is create onle one _*horizontalLinearLayout* with horizontal orientation. Then put two textViews in it, but you need to play with margin of second TextView.

Lastly, if I were you, I would create separate layout file for one row (so horizontal LinearLayout with two textViews). Then you get all positioning in XML, not in code. Adding layout to view:

```
View onewRow = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.one_row, null, false);
TextView tv1 = onewRow.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView tv2 = onewRow.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv1.setText("Flag");
tv2.setText("Your value");
root.addView(onewRow);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am actually parsing data dynamically and i also created one layout for two textviews but still i am getting second textview in zigzag style